# JSQMessageViewController Implementation

Tags: ios, messaging

I have integrate  JSQMessagesViewController  For Chat, I have an issue to differentiate sender and receiver message show right side and left side. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: do you have sender and receiver id of each message?

Comment: Yes I have both sender Id - @ivarun

Comment: ok good. could you add code what you have done so far.

Comment: Lot's of collection view methods in that. - ivarun

Comment: ok then add `messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt`  method code.

Comment: please edit question then add method code. Add `messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt` not  `avatarImageDataForItemAt  `

Comment: Done in below answer.

Comment: ok what output you are getting now? how bubbles are showing?

Comment: Bubbles are showing in left side only.

Comment: do you have any outgoing message in `messages` array? and what is in `self.senderId`

Comment: Yes i have messages in outgoing array but self.senderId is nil.

Comment: then you should set your own id in `self.senderId` first. your condition in `messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt ` in going in else part. that's why all bubbles are showing in left side only.

Comment: Okay I will try. Thank you

Comment: let me know it is work for you or not.

Comment: Not working proper when i pass same sender id then display messages right side and sender id is different then show messages left side.

Comment: it's working fine. Thanks - ivarun

Comment: ok now adding in answer. please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your own `userId` in `self.senderId` first as your condition in messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt in going in else part. that's why all bubbles are showing in left side only.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource {

    return messages[indexPath.item].senderId == self.senderId ? outgoingBubble : incomingBubble
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chat Controller Configuration:

1): If you are using JSQMessagesViewController than your chat controller should be inherited from JSQMessagesViewController.

2): JSQMessagesViewController have attributes of names senderId, senderDisplayName, myImage. So you assign these attributes with the login user Id,displayName and Image like (self.senderId = loginUser.id etc), because login user are sender.

```
  self.senderId = loginUser.uniqueId;
  self.displayName = loginUser.dispalyName; // if you have
  self.otherImage = [[JSQMessagesAvatarImage alloc] 
  initWithAvatarImage:"loginUserImage if you have" 
  highlightedImage:"highlitedImage if you have" 
  placeholderImage:"placeholder image if you have"];
```

3): JSQMessagesViewController also have attribute of name otherImage. so you should assign this property with other user image through which you like to chat like.

```
  self.otherImage = [[JSQMessagesAvatarImage alloc] 
  initWithAvatarImage:"userImage if you have" 
  highlightedImage:"highlitedImage if you have" 
  placeholderImage:"placeholder image if you have"];
```

NOTE: you should do this configuration in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear().This code is in objective-C so you can use accordingly.
Hope this will help you.